# Why the Informal Definition of a Cardinal Number doesn't work in ZFC

Tags: set-theory

On pages 109-110 of Patrick Suppes' book titled "Axiomatic Set Theory", the cardinal number of A, denoted $\bar{\bar{A}}$ can be defined as the set of all sets equipollent to it, but he states that within ZFC we cannot show that $\bar{\bar{A}}$ is a set other than the empty set. The Wikipedia page for [Cardinal assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_assignment) also states that this collection is too large to be a set.

Why is this so? Why can't we use this that definition as a formal definition of the cardinal numbers?

(The book then proceeds with introducing a new special axiom, instead of relying on a rank of a set or ordinals to define cardinals).

Comment: ZFC cannot build sets this big.  (Except for $\varnothing$.)  If we imagine the set $U_1$ of all one-element sets, then the set $\big\{ x : \{x\} \in U_1\big\}$ exists and is the set $V$ of everything.  Then Russel's paradox is a fatal flaw.

Comment: Thank you! I completely understand now why this naive definition is impossible as a basis for cardinals since in ZF, there is no such thing as the set V of all elements.

Answer (score 3):

Your textbook and the corresponding Wikipedia page already explained well why it cannot be a set: *It is too large to be a set.* However, the reasoning on this line may not capture what actually happens formally and historically.

Cantor's first set theory allowed defining sets from *unrestricted* separation, so, $\{x\mid \phi(x)\}$ is a set if $\phi(x)$ is a reasonable property. However, his unrestricted separation turned out to be inconsistent: Russell's paradox is one of the contradictions that unrestricted separation derives from.

Thus set theories appeared later imposed a restriction on Separation. What $\mathsf{ZFC}$ takes is setting a *domain* of Separation, which means, we can form a set $\{x\in a\mid \phi(x)\}$ only when we specify a set $a$.
Of course, restricted separation itself is not enough to construct 'larger' sets like $\{a,b\}$ or a union of two sets. This is the reason why we added other axioms into $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

However, collections of sets that are not sets are still useful in working set theory. Thus we call collections that are not guaranteed to be sets *proper classes.* Formally, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ does not think proper classes as valid objects in the domain of discourse. Instead, proper classes $\{x \mid \phi(x)\}$ are syntactic sugar for formulas $\phi(x)$. We may work with formulas directly, but using classes sometimes allow generalizing ideas applied to sets to *classes* which is sometimes more natural to understand.

Then when collections are proper classes? Typically, they become proper classes when they have too many elements: The collection of all sets $V$ is an example. Another example is the collection of all ordinals (follows from Burali-Forti Paradox.)

---

We may tempt to define cardinals in the naive way you suggested, by letting
$$|a| = \{b \mid \text{There is a bijection between $a$ and $b$}\}.$$
The natural problem we can raise is whether $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can prove $|a|$ exists, or put it differently, whether $|a|$ is a set. The answer is no, and in fact, we can find a *pattern* to correspond to every set into an element of $|\{0\}|$: For each set $x$, $\{x\}$ is a singleton, so $|\{0\}|$ contains all such $\{x\}$. However, you can see that if $|\{0\}|$ is a set, then
$$\{\{x\}\mid x\in V\}$$
is also a set, and so $V$ is also a set by Replacement, which is impossible. We can also say that $|\{0\}|$ has many elements as $V$ has.

---

However, there is a way to use your naive definition with no significant modification through [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick). The idea of Scott's trick is restricting the size of a proper class by collecting elements of the least rank in the proper class. Of course, the resulting set does not contain all elements of the proper class, but we can still think the subset we get through the trick still represents the collection quite well. In our case of defining cardinals, the "set" $|a|$ obtained by Scott's trick does not contain all sets whose cardinality is equal to $a$ (possibly $a$ itself!), but all sets in $|a|$ have the same cardinality with $a$.

---

*(There is another way to impose a restriction to Separation: restrict $\phi$ to be stratified ones, and it is what Quine's New Foundation took. However, let me not explain this side.)*

Comment: Thank you for this very informative response! Suppes' book actually discusses three ways to define cardinal numbers without crossing into this problem we had in this naive definition: introduce a new axiom (which is what he did for that chapter), define cardinals from ordinals (defined in the latter part of the book which requires AoC), or by using the rank of a set from Dana Scott (which is what you discussed), but this is not discussed in that book.

Comment: @howardnicko Ironically, introducing a new axiom is not what working set theorists do. Set theorists usually take the second option, and choose the third if they need to work without Choice. I believe your textbook may explain about the distinction between sets and proper classes in earlier chapters, which might be helpful to clarify the point (if it is.)

Comment: It does not, but I read about the distinction between the two upon further reading in other textbooks and resources.

Comment: Is there any problem in reasoning with cardinals/ordinals as proper classes?

Comment: Currently, I am working and studying within ZFC Set Theory, which has no proper classes in its universe of objects.

Comment: My question for @HanulJeon, is that what is the problem in considering the cardinality relation and *never* talk about cardinal *numbers*, in other words is Scott's trick a gimmick?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I could not get the whole point of your question, so, did you ask if it is okay to work with cardinality relation only and not consider cardinal numbers?

Comment: @HanulJeon Yes that’s my question.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku This approach has no problem, and in fact, you will be forced to work in this way if neither AC nor Scott's trick are available.

Comment: OK, so the answer I guess is that we need alephs, but it is fine if we abandon cardinals? Yes? Then why do all books working without choice, work with cardinals, when they could instead work with the cardinality relation?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku The only role of cardinals is representing a "number of elements" by using a single set, so yes, if you do not mind there are no such representatives. But some books working without Choice still mention cardinals, and these are defined by Scott's trick.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku You may state facts on cardinals without cardinals by simply putting sets instead of cardinals and the equipotency relation instead of the equality, etc. But it is a more cumbersome to write and... we are accustomed to think with cardinals.